# asp.net MVC RC1 RenderPartial ViewDataDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a `ViewData` object from a master page to a view user control using the `ViewDataDictionary`.

The problem is the `ViewDataDictionary` is not returning any values in the view user control whichever way I try it.

The sample code below is using an anonymous object just for demonstration although neither this method or passing a `ViewData` object works.

Following is the `RenderPartial` helper method I'm trying to use:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", ViewData.Eval("Projects"), new ViewDataDictionary(new { Test = "Mark" })); %>
```

and in my view user control i do the following:

```
<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Test"]) %>
```

Why does this not return anything?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I'm able to pass and access the strongly typed model without any problems. it's the `ViewDataDictionary` which I'm trying to use to pass say just a single value outside of the model...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", ViewData); %>
```

Also have you verified ViewData["Test"] is in the ViewData before you are passing it?  Also note that when passing your ViewData to a Partial Control that it is important to keep the Model the same.

Nick

Comment: Thanks but I'm able to pass the model without any problems. it's the ViewDataDictionary which i'm trying to use to pass say just a single value outside of the model..

Answer (score 36):

This is the neatest way I've seen to do this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", Model, new ViewDataDictionary{{"key","value"}});%>
```

It may be a little hackish, but it let's you send the model through AND some extra data.

Answer (score 13):

Don't know if anyone still cares but I used a KeyValuePair for the ViewDataDictionary.

```
 <% Html.RenderPartial("ItemRow", item, new ViewDataDictionary{
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("url", url),
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("count", count),
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("className", className)
 }); %>
```

This way you can write everything in one statement. The KVPs can be accessed in the view by:

```
<%= ViewData["url"] %>
<%= ViewData["count"] %>
<%= ViewData["className"] %>
```

While what I passed through the model can be accessed through Model.*

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the RTM version of ASP.Net MVC, but with:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", new ViewDataDictionary(new {Key = "Some value"})); %>
```

Try the following when referencing the value in your partial view:

```
<%= ViewData.Eval("Key") %>
```

That seems to have done the trick for me. It will also work if you just do this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", new {Key = "Some value"}); %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your main view:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", ViewData["Projects"]); %>
```

Either in you controller or your main view:

```
ViewData["Test"] = "Mark";
```

If you don't specify a model or view data dictionary in RenderPartail, it uses the ones from the containing view.