# Shorthand for creating a ViewDataDictionary with both a model and ViewData items?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

Is there any way to create a `ViewDataDictionary` with a model and additional properties with a single line of code. I am trying to make a `RenderPartial` call to a strongly-typed view while assembling both the model and some extra display configuration properties without explicitly assembling the ViewDataDictionary across multiple lines. It seems like it would be possible given the `RenderPartial` overload taking both a model `object` and a `ViewDataDictionary` but it looks like it simply ignores the `ViewDataDictionary` whenever they are both populated.

```
// FAIL: This will result in ViewData being a ViewDataDictionary
// where Model = MyModelObject and there are no other parameters available.
this.Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialView", MyModelObject, new ViewDataDictionary(new { SomeDisplayParameter = true }));
```

I found someone else with the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495351/asp-net-mvc-rc1-renderpartial-viewdatadictionary), but their solution is the same multi-line concept I found: create a discrete `ViewDataDictionary` with the model, add the new parameter(s) and use it in the `RenderPartial` call.

```
var SomeViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(MyModelObject);
SomeViewData.Add("SomeDisplayParameter", true);
this.Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialView", SomeViewData);
```

I can always wrap that logic into a `ChainedAdd` method that returns a duplicate dictionary with the new element added but it just seems like I am missing some way of creating a `ViewDataDictionary` that would do this for me (and that is a bit more overhead than I was hoping for).

```
this.Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialView", new ViewDataDictionary(MyModelObject).ChainedAdd("SomeDisplayParameter", true));

public static ViewDataDictionaryExtensions {
    public static ViewDataDictionary ChainedAdd(this ViewDataDictionary source, string key, object value) {
        return source.ChainedAdd(new KeyValuePair<string,object>(key, value));
    }
    public static ViewDataDictionary ChainedAdd(this ViewDataDictionary source, KeyValuePair<string, object> keyAndValue) {
        ViewDataDictionary NewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(source);
        NewDictionary.Add(keyAndValue);
        return NewDictionary;
    }
}
```

As well, trying to assemble a `ViewDataDictionary` with an explicit `Model` and `ModelState` simply causes a compilation error because the ModelState is read-only.

```
// FAIL: Compilation error
this.Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialView", new ViewDataDictionary { Model = MyModelObject, ModelState = new ViewDataDictionary( new { SomeDisplayParameter = true }});
```

**ANSWER(S):** It looks like Craig and I ended up finding two separate syntaxes that will get the job done. I am definitely biased in this case, but I like the idea of setting the model first and "decorating" it afterwards.

```
new ViewDataDictionary(MyModelObject) { { "SomeDisplayParameter", true }, { "SomeOtherParameter", 3 }, { "SomeThirdParameter", "red" } };

new ViewDataDictionary(new ViewDataDictionary() { {"SomeDisplayParameter", true }})
    { Model = MyModelObject };
```

Of course, I would still be spinning my wheels without his [eventually spot-on] answer, so, circle gets the square.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use an [object initializer](http://blogs.msdn.com/howard_dierking/archive/2007/08/13/c-3-0-object-initializers.aspx) and collection initializers:

```
new ViewDataDictionary(new ViewDataDictionary() { {"SomeDisplayParameter", true }})
    {
        Model = MyModelObject
    }
```

The inner ViewDataDictionary gets its collection initialized, then this populates the "real" ViewDataDictionary using the constructor overload which takes ViewDataDictionary instead of object. Finally, the object initializer sets the model.

Then just pass the whole thing without setting MyModelObject separately:

```
this.Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialView", null, 
    new ViewDataDictionary(new ViewDataDictionary() { {"SomeDisplayParameter", true }})
        { Model = MyModelObject });
```

Comment: That appears to create a ViewDataDictionary with Model equal to the anonymous object and then replaces the Model property with MyModelObject afterwards, leaving no appended properties. It did teach me that I could combine a constructor with additional initializers; something I didn't know--thanks.

Comment: I just checked the source code. Setting Model does not clear the dictionary.

Comment: I agree; setting the model doesn't clear the dictionary. But you are not setting the dictionary in this code. You create a ViewDataDictionary with a Model of the anonymous object containing the SomeDisplayParameter property. Then, with the initializer, you change the Model to MyModelObject.

Comment: I see what you mean. The ViewDataDictionary(ViewDataDictionary) and ViewDataDictionary(object) constructors work differently. I'll update the example).

Comment: I found a syntax that works (next answer), but I have no clue what is happening behind the scenes to get it to work. I imagine if I waded through the MVC source, I would probably be able to follow the logic used in this particular initializer syntax.

Comment: My updated answer already explained *why* that works; it just uses the reverse order of operations. Either way works.

Answer (score 12):

Using Craig's answer as a starting point--I didn't even know you could combine both a constructor call and an object initializer--I stumbled on this [snippet](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/viewdata-mechanics-and-segmentation-excerpt-from-asp.net-mvc-in-action/) from Palermo that leads to a combination that works. He uses some sort of dictionary shorthand that somehow ends up populating the `ModelState` when consumed by the `ViewDataDictionary` object initializer.

```
new ViewDataDictionary(MyModelObject) { { "SomeDisplayParameter", true }, { "SomeOtherParameter", 3 }, { "SomeThirdParameter", "red" } };
// Of course, this also works with typed ViewDataDictionary objects (what I ended up using)
new ViewDataDictionary<SomeType>(MyModelObject) { { "SomeDisplayParameter", true }, { "SomeOtherParameter", 3 }, { "SomeThirdParameter", "red" } };
```

I still don't see how this ends up working given that you cannot set the `ModelState` explicitly in an initializer, but it does seem to maintain both the original model object and the "appended" parameters for the view. There are definitely a number of other permutations of this syntax that do not work--you cannot combine the model with the dictionary in a single object or use object-initializer syntax for the dictionary values--but the above version seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension method on HtmlHelper to copy the property names and values from an anonymous object to a ViewDataDictionary.

**Sample**

```
Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialView", MyModelObject, new { SomeDisplayParameter = true })
```

**HtmlHelper Extension**

```
public static void RenderPartial(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName, object model, object viewData)
{
    var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
    foreach (var property in viewData.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        vdd[property.Name] = property.GetValue(viewData);
    }
    htmlHelper.RenderPartial(partialViewName, vdd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in old style mvc aspx view:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ContactPartial", Model.ContactFactuur, new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData ) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Factuur" } }); %>
```

the thing here is that in the constructor I use the current viewdata "new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData)" which is a viewdatadictionary containing the modelstate that I need for the validationmessages.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the exact same question.

What I thought might work was this (pardon the VB Razor syntax)

```
 @Code Html.RenderPartial("Address", Model.MailingAddress, New ViewDataDictionary(New With {.AddressType = "Mailing Address"}))End Code
```

But of course you get this error at run-time:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code

Message=The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'VB$AnonymousType_1`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ViewModel.Address'.

But what I found, is that what I really wanted was to use was Editor Template anyway.

Instead of RenderPartial use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.MailingAddress, "Address",  New With {.AddressType = "Mailing Address"})
```

An editor template is just a partial view that lives

~/Views/{Model|Shared}/EditorTemplates/templatename.vbhtml

My template for Address is a strongly-typed partial view, but the EditorFor method gives the ability to add additional view data items easily with an anon object.

In the example above I didn't need to include the template name "Address", since MVC would would look for a template with the same name as the model type.

You can also override the display template in the same way.