# MVC3 - Passing data beyond the model to Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to pass a piece of extra data along with a model to a Partial view?

E.G.

`@Html.Partial("_SomeTable", (List<CustomTable>)ViewBag.Table);`

Is what I have now.  Can I add something else without changing my Model?

`@Html.Partial("_SomeTable", (List<CustomTable>)ViewBag.Table, "TemporaryTable");`

I see [ViewDataDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.aspx) as a param.  I am not sure what this object does or if this meets my need.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

ViewDataDictionary can be used to replace the ViewData dictionary in the partial view... If you don't pass a ViewDataDictionary parameter then the parial's viewdata is the same as the parents.

An example of how to use it in the parent is:

```
@Html.Partial("_SomeTable", (List<CustomTable>)ViewBag.Table, new ViewDataDictionary {{ "Key", obj }});
```

Then within the partial you can access this obj as follows:

```
@{ var obj = ViewData["key"]; }
```

A completely different approach woud be to use the [Tuple](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/tuple-in-c-4-0/) class to group both the original model and extra data together as follows:

```
@Html.Partial("_SomeTable", Tuple.Create<List<CustomTable>, string>((List<CustomTable>)ViewBag.Table, "Extra data"));
```

The model type for the partial would then be:

```
@model Tuple<List<CustomTable>, string>
```

Model.Item1 gives the List object and Model.Item2 gives the string

Comment: I can't understand the syntax in `new ViewDataDictionary {{ "Key", obj }}`.
Where are the parentheses () in `new ViewDataDictionary()`

Comment: They are redundant when you have an object initializer.. which is what the code is directly after new ViewDataDictionary.. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Comment: `@{ var obj = ViewBag.Key; }` also works to access the passed data

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to just put it in the ViewBag and then access it from the ViewBag in the partial view. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729784/cant-access-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc3).

Answer (score 6):

I came across this issue as well.  I wanted to have a snippet of code reproduced many times, and did not want to copy paste. The code would vary slightly. After looking at the other answers, I did not want to go that exact route and decided instead to just use a plain `Dictionary`.

For example:

parent.cshtml

```
@{
 var args = new Dictionary<string,string>();
 args["redirectController"] = "Admin";
 args["redirectAction"] = "User";
}
@Html.Partial("_childPartial",args)
```

_childPartial.cshtml

```
@model Dictionary<string,string>
<div>@Model["redirectController"]</div>
<div>@Model["redirectAction"]</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get even clever [as shown here by Craig Stuntz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/608016/16940)

```
Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialView", null, 
    new ViewDataDictionary(new ViewDataDictionary() { {"SomeDisplayParameter", true }})
        { Model = MyModelObject });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the current `ViewData` contents to a new dictionary of entries to pass to a partial, you can do

```
@Html.Partial("_somepartial", Model,  new ViewDataDictionary (ViewData) { { "Name", "John" }, { "Surname", "Doe" } })
```

Notice the `ViewData` entering as a parameter on the constructor of the `ViewDataDictionary`.