# Accessing Viewbag data in rendered Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

The question might be a likely duplicate of
[Can't access ViewBag in a partial view in ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729784/cant-access-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc3),
but it does not seem to categorically negate the possibility.

The issue is to Access `ViewBag` Data in partial View which is being called from within the View and is being passed a model e.g.

```
@Html.Partial("name", object);
```

The the Action method for the main View from which this partial View is being called has a `Viewbag` property .. That `Viewbag` does not seem to be accessed with the `Partial view.`

Any help appreciated..

Comment: Did you see any errors, when you run your application ?

Comment: the object is intended to be casted to int .. when doing that, it says that a null object cannot be casted to non-nullable type int (or a similar error :)  )

Comment: that does not seem to be the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the time..

have found the solution in the following post

[MVC3 - Passing data beyond the model to Partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177153/mvc3-passing-data-beyond-the-model-to-partial-view)

Regards.