# Passing a string (besides the model) into a partial view in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

How can I send a string to a partial view?

What I would like is to send information about the model being viewed, to a partial view. Something like this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_PhaseCreate", new Phase(), @Model.Id );}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you use ViewBag? Set a value from controller or view and access it in partial view. Haven't checked myself yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177153/mvc3-passing-data-beyond-the-model-to-partial-view. In case there is a particular issue with what you are attempting, share the error or more data about the problem you are facing. There is many post describing how to achieve it normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send some data that isn't in model or view, you should use something like the following:

1) instead of `@Html.Partial()`, use a `@Html.Action("ActionName", "Controller", routeValues: new { id = Model.Id })` helper.

2) Add something like this to your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetMyView(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Phase = new Phase();
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    // also whatever which doesn't in model ...

    return View("_PhaseCreate");
}
```

And in your partial view, you can use those info just like you declare them:

```
<label>@ViewBag.Id</label>
```

You also can simply use the following if you just need to add data existing in model and the view:

```
@Html.Partial("_PhaseCreate", 
              new ViewDataDictionary(new { Phase = new Phase(), Id = Model.Id }))
```

and use them like this:

```
<label>@ViewData["Id"].ToString()</label>
```