# asp mvc partial with model and ViewDataDictionary - how do I access the ViewDataDictionary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a form which updates two related models, for this example a Project with a collection of Tasks, I want the controller to accept a single Project which has its Task collection loaded from the form input. I have this working, essentially the below code without a partial.

This might sound silly but I cannot figure out how to access the counter (i) from the partial?

Model

```
public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}
```

Create.cshtml (View)

```
@model MyWebApp.Models.Project

@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Project", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "project-form" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("Name", Model.Name)
    </div>

    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_TaskForm", Model.Tasks[i], new ViewDataDictionary<int>(i))
    }

}
```

_TaskForm.cshtml (partial view)

```
@model MyWebApp.Models.Task

<div>
    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("Tasks[{0}].Name", 0), Model.Name)
</div
<div>
    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("Tasks[{0}].DueDate", 0), Model.DueDate)
</div
```

NOTE the String.Format above I am hardcoding 0, I want to use the ViewDataDictionary parameter which is bound to the variable i from the calling View

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Guess I posted too soon. This thread had the answer I was looking for

[asp.net MVC RC1 RenderPartial ViewDataDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495351/asp-net-mvc-rc1-renderpartial-viewdatadictionary)

I ended up using this terse syntax

```
@Html.Partial("_TaskForm", Model.Tasks[i], new ViewDataDictionary { {"counter", i} } )
```

Then in partial view

```
@model MyWebApp.Models.Task
@{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["counter"]);
}

<div>
    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("Tasks[{0}].Name", index), Model.Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("Tasks[{0}].DueDate", index), Model.DueDate)
</div>
```